# Empty SQLite database on API 10

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to clear my SQLite database by deleting the associated db file and then recreating it.

However, I can't use `context.deleteDatabase()` for I'm working with the min API 10.

Any alternatives?

Comment: `deleteDatabase()` has been around since API 1. Are you using `Context.deleteDatabase( String )` -- a static call --, or `this.deleteDatabase( String )`? `deleteDatabase()` is not static.

Comment: nothing appears when I write Context.deleteDatabase( string )

Comment: No, nothing should appear. There's no static method `deleteDatabase()` on `Context`. Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); 
//helper is object extends SQLiteOpenHelper
db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS, null, null);
db.delete(DatabaseHelper.TAB_USERS_GROUP, null, null);
```

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin, sure you can. Why do you think you can't?